# gdal_translate and remote file location

Tags: gdal, esri-grid-format

Environment: Win10 and GDAL 2.1.0 in the OSGEO4W shell, 64 bit. Edits made below.

I have temporary access to a whole-of-country dataset in ESRI's Arc/Info binary grid format, which according to this - http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html - should be supported by gdal. Its accessible through webDAV.

The whole dataset is about 200GB, but I only need a small portion of it, so i would like to use something like

```
gdal_translate -projwin_src EPSG:4283 -projwin xmin ymin xmax ymax src_dataset=http://user:pass@path_to_file/w1001001.adf dst_dataset=local_path
```

to get the portion I need. The command fails out with error 4 'failed to create temporary file', because I don't have write access to the remote location.

I've tried incorporating "--config CPL_TMPDIR local_folder" into the command, and I've tried setting it separately (set CPL_TMPDIR=local_path), but that doesn't seem to help much. The next problem is error 4: "local_folder\w1001001.adf is not recognised as a supported file format', which contradicts the documentation.

**SOLVED:** per comment below, one must use vsicurl, e.g.

```
gdal_translate --config CPL_TMPDIR D:\local_folder -projwin_srs EPSG:4283 -projwin ulx uly lrx lry /vsicurl/http://user:pass@webdav-url/w001001.adf D:\local_folder\output.tif
```

works on both tif and adf source files.

Comment: That syntax looks wrong - the `src_file=` and `dst_file=` parts are bogus.

Comment: ....its a code snippet example, I've replaced the actual paths with a generic tag. You don't need to see the full paths on my machine to understand the command syntax.

Comment: I mean it should be `gdal_translate -projwin xmin ymin xmax ymax http://<remote_path> <local path>`. I'm not asking for the paths, I'm trying to make sure the basic syntax is OK.

Comment: oh i see what you mean now - the tags are actually -src_dataset -dst_dataset, but their use is optional. removing them has had no effect.

I've managed to get past the original error by making the --config CPL_TMPDIR=X the first parameter after 'gdal_translate', but now its saying that the .adf file is not supported, which contradicts the documentation...

Comment: You can ask gdal for the `--formats` that it supports. Unlikely you found a GDAL that doesn't have Arc/Info support, but it is possible.

Comment: --formats shows that the file should be supported.

Comment: Is it really a single file? Do you possibly need more of the data structure? Also, your edited example is still missing the `-` parts. Maybe trying cut-n-paste and be careful with the replacement of the actual paths.

Comment: Try `/vsicurl/http://the/url` http://erouault.blogspot.com/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html?m=1

Comment: `/vsicurl/` solved the issue! Thanks very much @Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `vsicurl` [virtual file system](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html?m=1) syntax.

```
/vsicurl/http://the/url
```

E.g

```
gdal_translate --config CPL_TMPDIR D:\local_folder -projwin_srs EPSG:4283 -projwin ulx uly lrx lry /vsicurl/http://user:pass@webdav-url/w001001.adf D:\local_folder\output.tif
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to build a VRT around the full datasource:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT http://user:pass@path_to_file/w1001001.adf local_path.vrt
```

and work on with that. GDAL tries to write its `.aux.xml` file next to the source file, and will fail on that with an external source.

Comment: Tried that. Seemed like it was working at first (lot of wifi activity at least) but after ~40 minutes it failed out with 'ERROR 1: Failed writing body (0 != 1380)